# Variable in variable

Tags: python-3.x

```
print("Hello Friend!")
myName = input("What is your name?")
print("Hello",myName)
myVar = input("How are you?")
if(myVar == "I'm good"):
    print("I'm happy to hear that",myName,".")
elif(myVar == "I'm ok"):
    print("I'm happy to hear that",myName,".")
elif(myVar == "I'm fine"):
    print("I'm happy to hear that",myName,".")
else:
    print("I'm sorry to hear that")
no1_Topic = input("What do you want to talk about?")
no2_Topic = input("Do you like",no1_Topic,"?")
if(no2_Topic == "Yes"):
    print("Me too.")
elif(no2_Topic == "No"):
    print ("Me neither")
```

This is practicly my very first own code and i'd really like to know, what do i screw up. If you could just comment the corrected version with some tiny explenation that'd be great as well. I will try to figure the most out on my own. Ohh , and excuse my english i'm only 17 and not a native speaker.

Comment: Could you describe the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: Yes, it says it expects most 1 argument and got 3 in the line:
    no2_Topic = input("Do you like",no1_Topic,"?")

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is that `input` only takes a single optional string that's displayed to the user as a prompt.

Instead of:

```
no2_Topic = input("Do you like",no1_Topic,"?")
```

Use string formatting to create a single string:

```
no2_Topic = input('Do you like {}?'.format(no1_Topic))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked, also if i may have an other question, what's the role of {} this? Does it insert what is after the .format command?

Comment: @BotondHorváth yup, it's a placeholder... `str.format` is very powerful - you can find all the info. regarding it in the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings

Comment: Thanks for your help mate, appriciate it:)